# How to replace a string containing spaces with something provided that the string occurs between slashes

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have string in python script running on MacOS High Sierra which contains a path

```
mystring = "/path/to/some dir/file"
```

I want to replace the space in `some dir` with "\ " which can be done like below I believe

```
mystring.replace(" ", "\ ")
```

**Question:**
What if I want to confirm that the space is found in path names enclosed between `/`s. I don't want to replace just any space with a `\`. I want to replace a path name which falls between `/`s with a `\`.

The output string needs to be like this

```
"/path/to/some\ dir/file"
```

I am using **python 3.6**

Comment: So you don't want to change `/path/file name` to `/path/file\ name`?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to do this? If you're passing this string to a shell that needs spaces to be escaped, I think it would need it done in the filename part as well, not just the directories.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just put quotes around the whole name, instead of escaping all the spaces?

Comment: Yes. But, I have some legacy code related compulsions and couldn't do that. Probably I should have used underscores for the question to focussed on the problem itself rather than other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string on `/` characters. Then loop through all but the last one, replacing spaces. Then join it back together.

```
arr = mystring.split('/')
for i in range(0, len(arr)-1):
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(" ", r"\ ")
mystring = "/".join(arr)
```